# Parametrizing solution surface in PDE $v_t-xv_x=1-v$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

The task is as follows:

> You are given the Cauchy problem for $v(x, t)$:
>   $$
> v_t(x, t) − xv_x(x, t) = 1 − v(x, t),\qquad
> −∞ < x < ∞,\; t > 0,
> $$
>   $$
> v(x, 0) = \sin x, \qquad −∞ < x < ∞.
> $$
>   (a) Determine the solution $v(x, t)$.

I parametrized with $t(s,0) = 0$, $x(s,0) = s$, and $v(s,0) = \sin(s)$. 
Basically I end up with

$v(s,τ) = [τ+\sin(s)]/(1+τ)$

$t(s,τ) = τ$, and $x(s,t) = s/(1+τ)$

I need $v$ in terms of the original $x$ and $t$, but can't figure out how to sub them back in. Could I have parametrized $v(s,0)$ differently perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us apply the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) to the Cauchy problem of the present PDE $v_t-xv_x=1-v$.

- $\text dt/\text ds = 1$, letting $t(0)=0$ we know $t=s$;
- $\text dx/\text ds = -x$, letting $x(0)=x_0$ we know $x = x_0e^{-s}$;
- $\text dv/\text d s = 1-v$, letting $v(0)=\sin x_0$ we know $v = 1 + (\sin x_0 -1)\, e^{-s}$

Combining everything, we find
$$
v(x,t) = 1 + (\sin (xe^t) -1)\, e^{-t} .
$$

Comment: Thanks!
As t -> infinity, u(x,t) -> 1 then?
and u_x(x,t) -> 0?

Comment: @OllieNichols Yes, apparently. Please use [Mathjax in future](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)